# Implementing equals, hashCode, and toString on java.lang.reflect.Proxy

Tags: java, reflection

I'm writing an application where I need to implement functional interfaces on runtime. I don't know in advance which interfaces to implement, but can resolve the `Method` object using reflection from the interface's `Class` object.

For the purpose of simplifying the question, let's say that I'm passing a `Function` object containing the implementation of the method.

Straight-forward stuff:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <T> T implement(Class<T> interfaceType, Method m, Function<Object[], ?> f) {
    return (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
            getClass().getClassLoader(),
            new Class<?>[]{interfaceType},
            (proxy, method, args) -> {
                if (method.equals(m)) {
                    return f.apply(args);
                }

                // Calls to toString, hashCode, and equals go here.
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(method.getName());
            }
    );
}
```

So calls to `toString`, `hashCode`, and `equals` currently fail. I clearly don't want that.

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) of `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`:

> An invocation of the `hashCode`, `equals`, or `toString` methods declared in `java.lang.Object` on a proxy instance will be encoded and dispatched to the invocation handler's invoke method in the same manner as interface method invocations are encoded and dispatched, as described above. The declaring class of the `Method` object passed to invoke will be `java.lang.Object`. Other public methods of a proxy instance inherited from `java.lang.Object` are not overridden by a proxy class, so invocations of those methods behave like they do for instances of `java.lang.Object`.

So I can override these methods however I want. That's cool, but I would prefer not to.

Sure, I could make dummy implementations that do more or less the same thing (except for `hashCode` which is `native`) or capture some other dummy object (maybe the invocation handler itself) and invoke the method on that one. But I feel like I should be able to just "fall through" to the methods inherited from `java.lang.Object` the usual way. Or in other words, call the equivalent of `super.hashCode()` etc. directly on `proxy`.

Is there a good/standard way of doing that?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to call a super method on anything but `this`. However the implementations for equals, hashCode and toString are pretty straight-forward, equals is just `==`, for hashCode there is `System.identityHashCode` and toString is `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`.

Comment: I think it's possible using reflection (`MethodHandles`) but clearly that's a huge overkill for this problem. I was hoping that I was missing some super simple trick. But I guess just implementing them as you propose is simple enough.

Comment: There is `InvocationHandler.invokeDefault` and `MethodHandles.lookup().findSpecial` that can both call default methods. But it is easier to hard code the 3 object methods.

Comment: What prevents you from saying `if (method.equals(m)) { ... } else method.invoke( obj, args );` where `obj` can be either `this` or `f` or whatever?

Comment: @MikeNakis The nautral fallback would be `method.invoke(proxy, args)` but that fails as the VM (strangely in my opinion) doesn't implement the `Object` methods for the proxy. Doing what you suggest works but it feels a little smelly to me to invoke these methods on objects other than the proxy itself (the context where I needed this was a little broader than presented here). In practice it's probably completely fine.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn This doesn't work as the methods are not automatically implemented: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: "public java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()" is not a default method`. I'll post the solution I ended up using back then.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the suggestions in the comments, I ended up defining the following base invocation handler:

```java
public class ObjectInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {
    public static final Method HASH_CODE;
    public static final Method EQUALS;
    public static final Method TO_STRING;
    
    static {
        Class<Object> object = Object.class;
        try {
            HASH_CODE = object.getDeclaredMethod("hashCode");
            EQUALS = object.getDeclaredMethod("equals", object);
            TO_STRING = object.getDeclaredMethod("toString");
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // Never happens.
            throw new Error(e);
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Exception {
        // The clone() method is not handled as there's no way to emulate the behavior of that method.
        // Implementers would have to implement cloning entirely in a subclass.
        if (method.equals(HASH_CODE)) {
            return objectHashCode(proxy);
        }
        if (method.equals(EQUALS)) {
            return objectEquals(proxy, args[0]);
        }
        if (method.equals(TO_STRING)) {
            return objectToString(proxy);
        }
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(method.getName());
    }
    
    public String objectClassName(Object obj) {
        return obj.getClass().getName();
    }
    
    public int objectHashCode(Object obj) {
        return System.identityHashCode(obj);
    }
    
    public boolean objectEquals(Object obj, Object other) {
        return obj == other;
    }
    
    public String objectToString(Object obj) {
        return objectClassName(obj) + '@' + Integer.toHexString(objectHashCode(obj));
    }
}
```

Then the proxy is then created using

```java
Proxy.newProxyInstance(
    interfaceType.getClassLoader(),
    new Class<?>[]{interfaceType},
    new ObjectInvocationHandler() {
        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Exception {
            if (method.equals(m)) {
                return f.apply(args);
            }
            return super.invoke(proxy, method, args);
        }
    }
)
```